# "Over beforehand" and "for" meaning in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I've been reading two sentences:

> **For** they had not married heedlessly in America.
>
> Although they have talked everything **over beforehand**.

In these two sentences, I'm not sure about the use of *for* and *over beforehand* (especially *over*). I know about *[beforehand](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/beforehand)*, Oxford Dictionaries say–

> - *Before an action or event; in advance*

but it's the *over* bit that is confusing me. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren’t related.

*For* means *because* or *since* ([ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/for)).

To *talk (something) over* is *to discuss a problem or situation with someone, often to find out their opinion or to get advice before making a decision about it* ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://www.google.com.au/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/talk-sth-over)).

Answer (score 2):

“For” in this context is a conjunction meaning “because”. And in “talking something over” the word “over” is a phrasal verb and used together mean to discuss something with someone.  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/talk-sth-over